# If url not equals to specific url then add condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, jquery-events

I am a template designer and I have some purchasable templates, but more often than not I find people share my template and redistributing them for free. so I would like a Javascript/jQuery to write that if the current url is not equal to specified url (`var url = blogurlhere`) then hide   or remove `<body>` to prevent people from copying my templates. Please, I really appreciate it.

Comment: And what will keep the thief from simply removing your JavaScript and living happily ever after?

Comment: jQuery and security go together like hipsters and mainstream; it's so easy to circumvent this is by far the worst way to validate. Think about it - they can take your template, remove the offending JS and distribute it as they would anyway.

Comment: What do you want to happen - the source of the pages to become 'invisible'? Even if this were possible, all they would have to do is disable JavaScript and it would get around this. Content theft on the web is unfortunately one of things you'll have to deal with. Media, content and code are all subject to it and there is no way you can stop it. It's the way the web works.

Comment: sorry i wasnt very clear. my templates will contain a lot of javascript within them for widgets etc so i will have it hidden within them. and yes i understand that it can still be removed but ohh well.

Comment: JavaScript-based 'security' isn't going to deter anyone that wants to trade your designs. Include copyright notices and links to your site, and use other peoples' distribution of your work as promotion for your future work. That's (probably) less work for you to implement, and probably reasonably likely to survive intact.

Comment: Still - fair enough. This will provide *some* security against the technology-illiterate thief. While far from a truly secure solution, it's not completely useless

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$(function() {
    var legitimate_url = 'http://blogurlhere.com';
    if ((document.location != legitimate_url) && (Math.floor(Math.random()*111) == 1)) {
        document.location = 'http://yoursite.com/stolen';
    }
});
```

Where http://yoursite.com/stolen displays the most embarassing message ever. Which will happen once in 100 times or so.

Base64encode that and put it into `eval()` and base64decode() respectively.

But frankly, that'll only keep the most stupid of people from "stealing" your stuff. There's not a whole lot that you can do against "piracy" of that kind.

**Edit:**

Depending on what system(s) you are developing your templates for, you could implement some additional server side layer of security:

For example, some (rather expensive) WordPress templates I have come across pull vital bits of their functionality from a remote server. The code responsible is somewhat obfuscated (though, again, it's obviously not impossible to decode for someone who knows their bits and bytes, thus enabling the person to simply pull the stuff in question from your server).

Also, well-buried killswitches are quite common in expensive Magento extensions. Basically, the underlying PHP polls the developers' server now and then, transmitting the domain it's being run on. This information is then matched against a license database - if no match is detected, the extension deletes a couple of its files and leaves a rather unfriendly message for the admin.

---

If – since you've been asking for a client-side solution, I assume this is the case – you're shipping somewhat pure HTML/CSS/JS to your customers, you're basically out of luck as far as technical solutions are concerned. Everything that happens client-side can (and therefor will) be circumvented by even moderately knowledgeable adversaries.

The best thing you can do in this case, is to offer "the pirates" incentives to legalize what they have "stolen" from you, i.e. by

- offering a discount on another theme of yours
- providing an hour or two of "free" customization support
- offering access to a "premium support" forum
- offering next day response on inquiries

… for those with a valid receipt number.

**tl;dr:** Some of the world's biggest companies (and industries) have constantly failed at protecting their stuff from "piracy". It is pretty unlikely that you will do any better. Give the customer a reason to buy from you rather than stealing. Or make your themes free in the first place and sell corresponding services.

Comment: would you know about copyrighting?

Comment: @user975763 Would _you_?

Comment: Copyrighting is a fairly huge legal issue; if you have questions as to copyright then you *really* need to speak to a lawyer/solicitor/counsel for your, or the relevant, jurisdiction.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you use `window.location` for this.

```
$(function() { if (window.location != 'http://www.template.com') { $(body).html(''); } });
```

Insert it on a hidden place. May I suggest somewhere in the jquery file? Noone would bother browsing through that file :)

Comment: This is really isn't a solution. Security-related stuff should _never_ be put in client side code. What's stopping someone just replacing `jquery.js`?

Comment: Nothing. Since it's in theory impossible to prevent it, you might aswell make it harder to do this, thus filtering the amount of people "stealing" it.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will be 100% safe, but you might want to obfuscate your HTML for a bit of extra protection. Searching for `HTML obfuscator` on Google should help.
There are plenty of code scramblers online. You could also make your templates in just JavaScript/jQuery and obfuscate that.
It looks very scary for people with basic knowledge, but like others are saying, you can't protect against ripping in JavaScript alone.